# Carrierwave or Paperclip: Keep image/file when updating other form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave, nested-forms

When using either Carrierwave or Paperclip everything works as expected with the exception of edit/update. When an image or file exists for a record it's set to nil on save if you don't explicitly upload another file.

What I've been looking for, but haven't found, is a solution that allows other form fields to be updated but keeps the existing file.  Unless, of course, the file is updated as well.

My setup is using nested models so for both Carrierwave and Paperclip I've tried the following no success.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-keep-%28not-replace%29-files-on-nested-edits

Apparently I'm missing something but I can't for the life of me figure out what.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some digging with pry I found a/the solution. First, here's the setup.

**The models**

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :machine
end
```

**The form**

```
= simple_form_for @machine do |m|
  ..... A bunch of inputs left out for brevity...
  = m.simple_fields_for :parts do |p|
    = p.input :name
    = p.input :location
    = p.input :price
    = p.file_field :image
```

**In the original Machine Controller - machine_posting_params**

```
def machine_posting_params
    params.require(:machine).permit(:name, part_attributes: [:name, :location, :price, :image])
end
```

**In the working Machine Controller - machine_posting_params**

```
def machine_posting_params
    params.require(:machine).permit(:name, part_attributes: [:name, :location, :price, :image, :id])
end
```

The problem, which I couldn't find any documentation for, is that :id is being passed into the part_attributes by, I believe, carrierwave.  When it isn't accounted for by part_attributes it causes carrierwave to dump the image reference on update.

So, if you have a nested form and your images keep disappearing on update try adding :id to xxxxx_attributs.  It works for Carrierwave but I see no reason this wouldn't work for Paperclip.  If I have time I'll switch and report back.

Answer (score 1):

I use Paperclip with nested_form and it's straight forward, no surprises.

Did you make sure to check if your nested record is a new record or already existing? You only want to display the file_field if it's actually a new record, otherwise display the image (or anything but the file_field). However that's what your link already explained.

Additionally could you post which params are sent on submit - check your logs to do that.

Comment: Hey thirdsun thanks for the response.  I just now noodled it out.  Please my answer to my question.